# transforming contour plot labels produced by direct.label()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Does anyone know how to add a constant to the labels that `direct.label()` function creates to label the isolines of a contour plot?

Basically, if the labels displayed for 3 isolines are 5, 10, 15 what I want is to transform these values (for example by adding a constant = 3) to label the isolines as 8, 13, 18

Much appreciated